# using AND/OR operators together

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to color a row if the following is true: column E is less than 50 days old AND if column F does not contain the word exempt OR NA.

So initially i tried
=OR(AND($E$4:$E>TODAY()-50, $F$4:$F <> "Exempt"), AND($E$4:$E>TODAY()-50, $F$4:$F <> "NA"))
but that did not work. Can anyone steer me the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your range selected (starting in the 4th row), try this formula.

```
=AND($E4>TODAY()-50, AND($F4 <> "Exempt", $F4 <> "NA"))
```

You only need to make the first row resolve as TRUE. With the relative cell row addresses, the formula will adjust for rows further down. You can put that formula into an unused cell on the 4th row and fill down to check the results.

Comment: One more question. when I have exempt or NA already in the sheet and someone starts typing either one, it'll autocomplete with an extra space which messes up the whole thing. Is there an 'NOT LIKE' operator? OR would I have to do something like =AND($E4>TODAY()-50, AND($F4 <> "Exempt", $F4 <> "NA",  $F4 <> "Exempt ",  $F4 <> "NA ")). Which I kind of don't want to do in case people get creative and start accidently adding spaces elsewhere